# How to add in 4 alphanumeric with space in Text Input?

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

I would like to add a TextInput in this format:-

XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX

for XXXX can be alphabet or numeric.

I getting this code but it just apply for numeric only.

```
_handlingCardNumber(number) {
  this.setState({
    cardNumber: number.replace(/\s?/g, '').replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').trim()
  });
}
```

How can I do it for numeric & string?

Please help.

Comment: `\d` matches any digit (0-9) so change `/(\d{4})/g` to `/([\dA-Z]{4})/gi` which will match digits (`\d`) and alpha chars (`A-Z`). The added `i` at the end makes it case-insensitive,which means `A-Z` will also match `a-z`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work.

`number.replace(/\s?/g, '').replace(/(\d{4}|[a-zA-z]{4})/g, '$1 ').trim()`

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to replace alphanumeric string, you can use `\w` to match that, which equals to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`:

```js
var number = "82ac3bd4 rtfs 6738";

var cardNumber = number.replace(/\s?/g, '').replace(/(\w{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();

console.log(cardNumber);
```